# How to test Devise's 'timeoutable' module?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, devise

I am trying to test a session timeout in my Rails 4.2 app using Devise. I have added `:timeoutable` in the relevant model. I have `Devise::TestHelpers` included, and I use `sign_in` and `sign_out` in my tests.

Here are the three things I have tried, none of which work. I know that if I do a `sign_out` explicitly instead of any of these, the test succeeds (basically, assert a redirect to the sign in page.)

What am I doing wrong?

**With `ActiveSupport::Testing::TimeHelper`**

 `# before stuff
 travel_to(later) do
   # after stuff
 end`

**With `Timecop`**

  `# before stuff
  Timecop.travel(later)
  # after stuff`

**With stubbing**

  `t = Time.now + later.minutes
  # before stuff
  Time.stubs(:now).returns t
  # after stuff`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [`Timecop.scale`](https://github.com/travisjeffery/timecop#timecopscale) as well?

In my experience, not all aspects of Devise work well with Timecop. Right now, I’m running into a few problems with `:timeoutable`, the value set on `timeout_in` is not taking `Timecop.freeze` date in consideration.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that Timecop was working fine with Devise in some of my Capybara tests but not in others. The difference was that in the ones that were working, I was opening a simulated mailbox using `capybara-mail`, and in the ones that weren't working, I wasn't doing anything which would force the page reload that would get Devise to do its timeoutable thing.

So instead of:

`before { Timecop.travel(Time.now + 31 * 60) }`

Try this:

`before do
  Timecop.travel(Time.now + 31 * 60)
  visit some_path
end`

This worked for me...